# Finding all $\alpha$ such that the linear system has infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the linear system:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 5\\
4 & 2 & 2 & 6\\
-2 & \alpha & 3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to find all $\alpha$ such that the system has infinitely many solutions. From what I've seen, there must be two equations that are multiples of each other so that they cancel out. I don't see an $\alpha$ that could work, so is there no $\alpha$ such that the system has infinitely many solutions?

Also, for a $3 \times 3$ matrix, how do you generally find $\alpha$ such that it has infinitely many solutions? I've only found examples for $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 5\\
4 & 2 & 2 & 6\\
-2 & \alpha & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 & 5\\
0 & 4 & \!\!\!-4 & \!\!\!-4\\
0 & \alpha-1 & 6 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So how can you do to have one row linearly *dependent* on the other two?

Spoiler!

> $\,\alpha=-5\,$

Comment: Why DonAntonio, is it that one row is dependent on the other two?